# Automatic Cycle Count Tracker

Tags: powerbi

```
Counted Status = If('Locations master'[loc_status] = 0 , If(AND('Locations master'[loc_status] = 0 ,'Locations master'[loc_alias] IN  DISTINCT('All Cycle Counts Exacta'[location])) , "Complete", "Incomplete"),BLANK())
```

Can someone help me interpret this code? I am trying to update an automatic cycle count tracker in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

If loc_status=0 we implement the second condition: loc_status=0  AND loc_alias is in the list of distinct locations. If our second condition is true, then Counted Status equals to Complete, otherwise Counted Status equals to Incomplete. If our first condition is false, then  Counted Status is blank. DAX formatter or similar tools could help to make code more readable:

```
Counted Status =
IF (
    'Locations master'[loc_status] = 0,
    IF (
        AND (
            'Locations master'[loc_status] = 0,
            'Locations master'[loc_alias]
                IN DISTINCT ( 'All Cycle Counts Exacta'[location] )
        ),
        "Complete",
        "Incomplete"
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```